# Why does an error occur in the telegram bot - RequestError: Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 2001:67c:4e8:f004::9:443

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

Why does an error occur in the telegram bot?
There is a telegram bot on nodejs with webhook.
Works fine. But after a long pause (before 40 minutes), when using the bot, it responds only 2 times. The first time you call any command, the bot gets an error:
RequestError: Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 2001:67c:4e8:f004::9:443

The second time you press, the bot responds and everything works well. After a pause, then again responds only from 2 times

Why can this happen?

Comment: Same here! Does anyone found the solution?